# Dreamweaver shows red label for javascript

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

Does anyone know what could be wrong with this code? It is showing a red label in Dreamweaver

```
$('#left_bar .cart-info').append('<div>'+localStorage["myid"] = document.getElementById("myid").value =parseInt(localStorage["myid"] || "0", 10) + 1;+'<input id="myid" type="text" name="itemquantity[]" value="1"/></div>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
$('#left_bar .cart-info').append('<div>' + (localStorage["myid"] = document.getElementById("myid").value = parseInt(localStorage["myid"] || "0", 10) + 1) + '<input id="myid" type="text" name="itemquantity[]" value="1"/></div>');
```

You have a misplaced semi-colon, and should surround your affectation with parenthesis to distinguish `+` semantics (addition vs. concatenation).